# UWSGI for https configuration is not working

Tags: uwsgi, libssl

UWSGI Version- 2.0.18

Openssl- 1.0.2k-fips

Python 2.7

Getting Error:

```
uwsgi: error while loading shared libraries: libssl.so.1.0.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When ever we do pip install uWSGI, It automatically binds to openssl libs.

But make sure you have installed openssl and openssl-devel package.

I tried with following versions:

Python- 3.6

UWSGI- 2.0.18

Commands:

Create Virtual Env and install flask and uWSGI:

```
virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.6 testing
source testing/bin/activate
pip install flask
pip install uWSGI
```

Create Certs:

```
openssl genrsa -out foobar.key 2048
openssl req -new -key foobar.key -out foobar.csr
openssl x509 -req -days 365 -in foobar.csr -signkey foobar.key -out foobar.crt
```

Create Sample Python file: foobar.py

```
def application(env, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type','text/html')])
    return [b"Hello World"]
```

Run uWSGI:

```
uwsgi --shared-socket 0.0.0.0:443 --uid roberto --gid roberto --https =0,foobar.crt,foobar.key --wsgi-file foobar.py
```

Make sure do not get confused with the uWSGI installed in a virtual environment and with root user.

Follow the documentation:

https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/WSGIquickstart.html